# Scala: abstract classes instantiation with trait?

Tags: scala

This a example code in the book:

```
abstract class Check {
  def check():String = "Checked Application Details... "
}
trait EmploymentCheck extends Check{
  override def check():String = "Check Employment ... " + super.check()
}

val app = new Check with EmploymentCheck
```

Which make me confused is the `new Check`, How can we instantiation a abstract class ? And why it will work by `with EmploymentCheck` ?

Answer (score 4):

`new Check with EmploymentCheck` generates an anonymous concrete subclass of `Check`. No abstract class is instantiated.

```
scala> app.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: EmploymentCheck] = class $anon$1
```

Comment: Is it equals: class APP1 extends Check with EmploymentCheck{}, and then: new APP1()

Answer (score 1):

The type you are instantiating is `Check with EmploymentCheck` not `Check`, and `Check with EmploymentCheck` is not abstract because the abstract member `check` has been filled in by `EmploymentCheck`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the type instantiated is an anonymous class extending `Check with EmploymentCheck`.

Comment: You're right, also probably the semantics will be different with stuff like singleton/dependent types, so the distinction is not a purely technical one.